# How to correctly punctuate a question with an alternative?

Tags: questions

How do I punctuate this sentence? When I say it, I raise my voice on the word `available`, which leads me to think there should be a question mark there. But I also learned in grade school to never start a sentence with `Or` (I know there can be exceptions; I'm just not a strong enough linguist to know what they are). The second part of the two part question looks like a question, but isn't said like a question, which throws me a little bit. I don't want the reader raising his voice on the word `guarantee`.

> Is the second option still available? Or do you not honor your guarantee?
>
> Is the second option still available? Or do you not honor your guarantee.
>
> Is the second option still available, or do you not honor your guarantee?
>
> Is the second option still available, or do you not honor your guarantee.

Comment: Versions 2 and 4 are best. The second part is a rhetorical question, but still a question. Is it not? You have found that special case where 'Or' starts a sentence just right by adding the drama you seek.

Answer (score 2):

I think the third option is grammatically correct, for formal written English, but the first might work for reported speech.

If you were saying that in a shop, there might be a significant pause before "Or," which warrants it going into a separate sentence in my opinion. Spoken English is not necessarily perfectly correct English!